# Android. It's okay to init objects outside of onCreate() lifecycle method?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have some utils and workers in my project. All of these classes works as singleton. Suppose that I have multimple activities where this objects used but is there a difference between

```
private LocationWorker mLocationWorker;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);
    mLocationWorker = LocationWorker.getInstance();
```

and this?

```
LocationWorker mLocationWorker = LocationWorker.getInstance()
```

It's okay to get references to this objects before onCreate() method?

Comment: I think that would be a bad practice fro several reasons. What function would it serve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's okay to get references to this objects before onCreate() method?

Yes it is.

```
LocationWorker mLocationWorker = LocationWorker.getInstance();
```

should work fine.

However, since it is a singleton, I'm not sure there's much point saving a reference to it in a field. You could just do

```
LocationWorker.getInstance()
```

whenever you need it.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm saving references to avoid code duplication, because I didn't know about 

    LocationWorker.getInstance().methodName();

That solve all my problems and I can remove references to singletons

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer the first approach

```
private LocationWorker mLocationWorker;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_forecast);
    mLocationWorker = LocationWorker.getInstance();
```

because the object will be created only when needed. In the second approach you are creating a singleton object. The object takes memory even before when it is needed. Some situations I prefer the first approach are:

- If the same object will be used from different parts of the activity.
  Thus you do not want to check for null every time before use want a
  clean code and you want cleaner code.
- If there will be a single common object for the class that will not
  change through out. Usually you make it static. Good example is:
  String LOG_TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();
- If the object will be used frequently in your activity. For activity
  that makes frequent communication with the server, for example, you
  should create the object of the class which makes the communication
  this way. Additional example is

If the object will be used in certain part of the class, you should consider declaring it inside that class.